# Term Sets Guids after migration are wrong for migrated documents

Tags: sharepoint, migration, sharepoint-online, taxonomy-terms

I’m having a problem with my imported taxonomy from 2016 to SPO. All documents versions are ok and I can see all values in the Proprieties. If I update values from an imported column point to a Term give me “the given guid does not exist in the term store” if I upload a new one I can tag everything without problems.

In my research, I can see the IDs are different in the TaxonomyHiddenList, may be the problem, because someone migrated this local term store in the Wong way over the tenant. Or maybe a failed migration somewhere.

My question is there any way to fix this error, sync or do anything to this terms be available for the migrated documents?

Comment: It is recommended to copy the taxonomy from SharePoint Server to SharePoint Online using PowerShell to maintain the IDs of the terms, term sets, and term groups in those taxonomies Or using SPMT.

Comment: Reference: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1099878/Migrate-SharePoint-Taxonomy-Term-Stores-from-Share